# Sha 256 different in NodeJs and Flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter

I am using `crypto` package in Node.js and `crypto` package in flutter. But the Sha256 of same string results in different values. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is the dart code:

```
List<int> bytes1 = utf8.encode("abc-234-abc" + json.encode({
    "invoiceAmount": 3700.0,
    "notes": {
        "env": "np",
    }
})); // data being hashed
Digest digest1 = sha256.convert(bytes1);
 print(digest1)
```

This is the Node.js code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

crypto.createHash('sha256').update(`abc-234-abc`+JSON.stringify(
{
    "invoiceAmount": 3700.0,
    "notes": {
        "env": "np",
    }
})).digest('hex')
```

UPDATE:
I have noticed that Flutter Web seems to return the same hash that is generated in Node.js but Flutter Android returns a different hash. It may be a difference between Java and Node.js.

Comment: Did you compare the strings before hashing? JSON encoding is not strictly deterministic, the order of the keys, spaces etc may vary.

Comment: Yes I compared both strings they were identical

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this?